# How to get the total of given values in a loop?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to read an [external API](https://covidtracking.com/api) which gives the following definitions for each historical date:

```
state - State or territory postal code abbreviation.
positive - Total cumulative positive test results.
positiveIncrease - Increase from the day before.
negative - Total cumulative negative test results.
negativeIncrease - Increase from the day before.
pending - Tests that have been submitted to a lab but no results have been reported yet.
totalTestResults - Calculated value (positive + negative) of total test results.
totalTestResultsIncrease - Increase from the day before.
hospitalized - Total cumulative number of people hospitalized.
hospitalizedIncrease - Increase from the day before.
death - Total cumulative number of people that have died.
deathIncrease - Increase from the day before.
dateChecked - ISO 8601 date of the time we saved visited their website
hospitalizedCurrently - Number of individuals currently hospitalized.
hospitalizedCumulative - Total number of individuals that have been hospitalized, including those that have been discharged.
inIcuCurrently - Number of individuals currently in an ICU.
inIcuCumulative - Total number of individuals that have been in the ICU.
onVentilatorCurrently - Number of individuals currently on a ventilator.
onVentilatorCumulative - Total number of individuals that have been on a ventilator.
recovered - Total number of individuals that have tested negative after a previous positive test.
total - DEPRECATED Will be removed in the future. (positive + negative + pending). Pending has been an unstable value and should not count in any totals.
```

Now I am looping all dates and I am trying to know the total for a given time period, so let's say we want to have the total from date 1 until the last date, I do:

```
function updateUI(filtererdData, dateStart, dateEnd, firstRunMap) {

    // new state
    deaths = 0;
    hospitalized = 0;
    recovered = 0;
    positive = 0;
    hospitalizedCumulative = 0;
    inIcuCumulative = 0;
    onVentilatorCumulative = 0;
    pending = 0;
    negative = 0;
    tests = 0;
    hospitalisedNow = 0;
    intensiveCareNow = 0;
    onVentilatorNow = 0;
    name = 0;
    cases = 0;
    var totalDeaths = 0;

    // filtererdData has now STATE data, and not only 1 state

    filtererdData.forEach(state => {

        var stateName = state.name;

        // "state.data" will have an array of all dates in between
        state.data.forEach(stateDataPerDay => {
            if(stateDataPerDay.death) deaths += stateDataPerDay.deathIncrease;
            if(stateDataPerDay.hospitalized) hospitalized += stateDataPerDay.hospitalizedIncrease;
            if(stateDataPerDay.recovered) recovered += stateDataPerDay.recovered;
            if(stateDataPerDay.positive) positive += stateDataPerDay.positiveIncrease;
            if(stateDataPerDay.negative) negative += stateDataPerDay.negativeIncrease;
            if(stateDataPerDay.totalTestResults) tests += stateDataPerDay.totalTestResultsIncrease;
            if(stateDataPerDay.hospitalizedCumulative) hospitalisedNow += stateDataPerDay.hospitalizedCurrently;
            if(stateDataPerDay.inIcuCumulative) intensiveCareNow += stateDataPerDay.inIcuCurrently;
            if(stateDataPerDay.onVentilatorCumulative) onVentilatorNow += stateDataPerDay.onVentilatorCurrently;
            cases += positive + negative;
            // WRONG
            if(stateDataPerDay.length - 1) {
                console.log(stateDataPerDay.death);
            }
        });

        // end each state data to save

        // let's append the total to each state as well
        // deaths & hospitalized are the sum of all selected days
        state.totalDeaths = deaths;
        state.totalHospitalized = hospitalized;
        state.totalRecovered = recovered;
        state.totalPositive = positive;
```

But I am doing this wrong, the totals I am having are just wrong. I am confused if to have the `death` totals I should be using `.death` or `.deathIncrease` and how this should be added within the loop to use that total value later on in the code. And do this for `deaths`, `recovered`, `tests`.

Another question in regards of this data is: How do I know the total cases? Is it `positive + negative`? And if so, how would I do the total for each state to use it later?

For some of the data I don't want to display its total as I will show it in a graph trend but for deaths, recovered, cases and tests I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you never reset the counter for each state, the totals will be off like you said. Move these variables inside the loop:

```
filteredData.forEach(state => {
    deaths = 0;
    hospitalized = 0;
    recovered = 0;
    positive = 0;
    pending = 0;
    negative = 0;
    tests = 0;
    hospitalisedNow = 0;
    intensiveCareNow = 0;
    onVentilatorNow = 0;
    name = 0;
    cases = 0;
    ...
}
```

Each state would need a seperate variable.

Comment: Ok makes sense but how then would we be able to have the super total of deaths, recovered, tests and cases? I should have stated this too in the question

Comment: Create a seperate variable for super totals. OR later on, sum up the state totals.

Comment: `var cases= 0; filteredData.map(state => state.data).forEach(stateData => cases += stateData.positiveIncrease - stateData.negativeIncrease)`

Comment: actually god knows if by "cases" they mean positives or all tested ones, so positives + negatives, in that case should be positiveIncrease + negativeIncrease.

Comment: this could lead us to a negative result cases += stateData.positiveIncrease - stateData.negativeIncrease;

Comment: fix it as you please